# Select at least one checkbox in AngularJS from each table

Tags: angularjs, validation, checkbox

I have to validate a questionnaire before submitting it. The question-answer tables are generated dynamically from a JSON file. Before submitting the questionnaire, at least one answer should be checked **from each question**. For an unattempted question, it should validate as 'Please select at least one checkbox/answer'.

My problem: I am able to validate at least once checkbox selection for one question, but I not able to validate for all questions. It validates if any one of the checkbox is selected on whole page. I want each question should have at least one answer selected.

My code shows validation error [Please select at least one checkbox/answer'] even for the selected answer question. It should show validation error only on the questions which are not attempted [i.e. questions whose at least one answer is also not selected].

I have gone through multiple posts on AngularJS group check box validation, but I wasn't able to satisfy my problem.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance!

**quest_answer.json**

```
[
    {
      "id": "0",
      "header": "Fruits",
      "question": "Which fruit do you like?", 
      "answer": [
        {"aid": 0, "value" : "Apple", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 1, "value" : "Banana", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 2, "value" : "Strawberry", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 3, "value" : "Grapes", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 4, "value" : "Mango", "isChecked" : false}  
      ],
      "notes":""
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "header": "Vegetables",
      "question": "Which vegetable do you like?", 
      "answer": [
        {"aid": 0, "value" : "Potato", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 1, "value" : "Spinach", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 2, "value" : "Cabbage", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 3, "value" : "Brinjal", "isChecked" : false}
      ],
      "notes":""
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "header": "Color",
      "question": "Which color do you like?", 
      "answer": [
        {"aid": 0, "value" : "Red", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 1, "value" : "Orange", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 2, "value" : "Green", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 3, "value" : "Blue", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 4, "value" : "Pink", "isChecked" : false}
      ],
      "notes":""
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "header": "Animal",
      "question": "Which animal do you like?", 
      "answer": [
        {"aid": 0, "value" : "Monkey", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 1, "value" : "Dog", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 2, "value" : "Cat", "isChecked" : false},
        {"aid": 3, "value" : "Cow", "isChecked" : false}       
      ],
      "notes":""
    }
]
```

**questionnaire.html**

```
<div ng-init="init()">
<div class="module">
  <div class="module-head">
    <center><h3> <b>Evaluation</b> </h3></center>
  </div>
    <center>
  <div class="module-body" >
      <div> Questionnaire About the Project/Initiative</div>
      <hr>
      <form name="qForm" ng-submit="evaluate_Report(qForm.$valid)" novalidate>
      <hr>
        <div>Question Set</div>
      <hr>
      <div ng-repeat="myQuestion in questionnaire">
      <table id="personal_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="width:70%">                      
         <tbody>                         
           <hr>
           <center><thead>{{myQuestion.header}}</thead></center>
           <tr style="width:100%">                                  
            <th rowspan="{{questionnaire[$index].answer.length+1}}" scope="rowgroup"style="width:50%">
             {{myQuestion.question}}</th>                            
            <th  style="width:2%">:</th> 
            <th  style="width:48%">Tick all that apply  
               <div ng-show="qForm.$submitted && qForm.ansCheck.$error.required">
                Please select atleast one checkbox</div>
            </th> 
           </tr>
           <tr ng-repeat="answer in questionnaire[$index].answer">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ansCheck" ng-model="answer.isChecked" ng-change="selectAnswer($parent.$index, $index, answer)" ng-required="!anySelected($parent.$index,answer)" >                                                                  
            </td>
            <td> {{answer.value}} </td>                                 
           </tr>                                         
           <tr style="width:100%">                                  
            <td style="width:50%" id="q2">Special Notes</td>                             
            <td style="width:1%">:</td> 
            <td style="width:49%"><input type=text ng-model="personal_info_notes">
            {{myQuestion.notes}} </td>                          
           </tr>                           
         </tbody>                    
      </table>          
      </div>
      <center>
       <button type=submit id="btn_evaluate">Evaluate Report</button>
      </center>
      <hr>      
      <hr>  
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**questionnaire.js**

```
app.controller('questionnaire', ['$scope','$http','$sce','$routeParams',function($scope, 
                                      $http, $sce, $routeParams) {

    $scope.questionAttempted = []; // an array containing question ids which are attempted
    $scope.questionAnswerAttempted=[];//an array containing answers which are checked    

    $scope.init=function()
    {
        $http.get('quest_answer.json').then(function(questionnaireData){      
            $scope.questionnaire = questionnaireData.data; 
         });                    
    }    


    $scope.selectAnswer = function(qIndex, aIndex, selectedAnswer)
    {         
        var selectedIndex = $scope.questionAnswerAttempted.indexOf(selectedAnswer.value);  
        var selectedQuestion= $scope.questionAttempted.indexOf(qIndex);  

        if(selectedIndex == -1 && selectedAnswer.isChecked){        
            $scope.questionAnswerAttempted.push(selectedAnswer.value);          
            if(selectedQuestion == -1){
                $scope.questionAttempted.push(qIndex);                
            }
        }else if(!selectedAnswer.isChecked && selectedIndex != -1){
            $scope.questionAnswerAttempted.splice(selectedIndex,1);           
             var  aLength = $scope.questionnaire[qIndex].answer.length;      
                //Remove the question id from the questionAttempted array only if none of the answers are checked.
            if(aLength >0){
                   for(a=0;a<aLength;a++){
                       if($scope.questionnaire[qIndex].answer[a].isChecked){
                            console.log("Atleast one answer is checked for this question. 
                       So no of questions attempted remains same:" + $scope.questionAttempted.length);  
                           flag = false;
                           break;                           
                       }else{
                           flag = true;                                                    
                       }
                   }
                if(flag){
                    $scope.questionAttempted.splice(selectedQuestion,1);
                          console.log("No answers are checked for this question. So removing it");   
                          console.log("No of questions attempted after splicing:" + $scope.questionAttempted.length);
                }

            }            
        }        
    }

    // For ng-required attribute of checkboxes. Should return 'true' for attempted question and 'false' for unattempted question
    $scope.anySelected = function(qIndex,answer){
        var qaLength =$scope.questionAttempted.length;
          if(qaLength > 0){
              for(var q = 0; q < qaLength ; q++){                  
                  if($scope.questionAttempted[q] == qIndex ){  
                       return true;
                  }else{
                      return false;
                  }
              }             
          }else{
              return false;
          }     
    }

      $scope.evaluate_Report = function(isValid)
      {
          if(isValid){
              alert('Form is valid');
          }else{
              alert('Form is Incomplete');
          }
    }

}]);



    app.controller('questionnaire', ['$scope','$http','$sce','$routeParams',function($scope, $http, $sce, $routeParams) {

        $scope.questionAttempted = []; // an array containing question ids which are attempted
        $scope.questionAnswerAttempted=[];//an array containing answers which are checked    
        
        $scope.init=function()
        {
            $http.get('quest_answer.json').then(function(questionnaireData){      
                $scope.questionnaire = questionnaireData.data; 
             });                    
        }    
       
        
        $scope.selectAnswer = function(qIndex, aIndex, selectedAnswer)
        {         
            var selectedIndex = $scope.questionAnswerAttempted.indexOf(selectedAnswer.value);  
            var selectedQuestion= $scope.questionAttempted.indexOf(qIndex);  
           
            if(selectedIndex == -1 && selectedAnswer.isChecked){  
                $scope.questionAnswerAttempted.push(selectedAnswer.value);          
                if(selectedQuestion == -1){
                    $scope.questionAttempted.push(qIndex);                
                }
            }else if(!selectedAnswer.isChecked && selectedIndex != -1){
                $scope.questionAnswerAttempted.splice(selectedIndex,1);           
                 var  aLength = $scope.questionnaire[qIndex].answer.length;      
        //Remove the question id from the questionAttempted array only if none of the answers are checked.
                if(aLength >0){
                       for(a=0;a<aLength;a++){
                           if($scope.questionnaire[qIndex].answer[a].isChecked){
                                console.log("Atleast one answer is checked for this question. So no of questions attempted remains same:" + $scope.questionAttempted.length);  
                               flag = false;
                               break;                           
                           }else{
                               flag = true;                                                    
                           }
                       }
                    if(flag){
                        $scope.questionAttempted.splice(selectedQuestion,1);
                              console.log("No answers are checked for this question. So removing it");   
                              console.log("No of questions attempted after splicing:" + $scope.questionAttempted.length);
                    }
                    
                }            
            }        
        }
        
     // For ng-required attribute of checkboxes. Should return 'true' for attempted question and 'false' for unattempted question
        $scope.anySelected = function(qIndex,answer){
            var qaLength =$scope.questionAttempted.length;
              if(qaLength > 0){
                  for(var q = 0; q < qaLength ; q++){                  
                      if($scope.questionAttempted[q] == qIndex ){  
                           return true;
                      }else{
                          return false;
                      }
                  }             
              }else{
                  return false;
              }     
        }
        
          $scope.evaluate_Report = function(isValid)
          {
              if(isValid){
                  alert('Form is valid');
              }else{
                  alert('Form is Incomplete');
              }
        }
         
    }]);
    .module {
     
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1); */
     border-color: #e9e9e9;
     margin-bottom: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
       /* border-radius: 4px;*/
    /*    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);*/
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);    
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-bottom-color: #bbb;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }


    .module-head { 
     color: #767676;
     background-color: #f6f6f6;
     border-color: #e9e9e9;
     padding: 10px 15px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
     border-top-right-radius: 3px;
     border-top-left-radius: 3px;  
    }

    .module-head h3 {
     font-size: 20px;
     line-height: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     margin: 0;
     font-weight: bold;
    }

    .module-body {
     padding: 15px;
        width:1350px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!-- title and meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv='REFRESH' content='43200'/>
    <meta name="Pragma" content="no-cache;">
    <title>Web</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css"> 
      </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
      
    <div ng-init="init()">
    <div class="module">
      <div class="module-head">
        <center><h3> <b>Evaluation</b> </h3></center>
      </div>
        <center>
      <div class="module-body" >
          <div> Questionnaire About the Project/Initiative</div>
          <hr>
          <form name="qForm" ng-submit="evaluate_Report(qForm.$valid)" novalidate>
          <hr>
            <div>Question Set</div>
          <hr>
          <div ng-repeat="myQuestion in questionnaire">
       <table id="personal_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="width:70%">                      
                          <tbody>                         
                               <hr>
                              <center><thead>{{myQuestion.header}}</thead></center>
                            <tr style="width:100%">                                  
                                <th rowspan="{{questionnaire[$index].answer.length+1}}" scope="rowgroup"style="width:50%">{{myQuestion.question}}</th>                         
                                <th  style="width:2%">:</th> 
                                <th  style="width:48%">Tick all that apply  <div ng-show="qForm.$submitted && qForm.ansCheck.$error.required">Please select atleast one checkbox</div>                                                                      </th> 
                            </tr>
                             <tr ng-repeat="answer in questionnaire[$index].answer">
                             <td><input type="checkbox" name="ansCheck" ng-model="answer.isChecked" ng-change="selectAnswer($parent.$index, $index, answer)" ng-required="!anySelected($parent.$index,answer)" >
                                                                               
                                 </td><td> {{answer.value}} </td>                                 
                              </tr>                                         
                             <tr style="width:100%">                                  
                                <td style="width:50%" id="q2">Special Notes</td>                         
                                <td style="width:1%">:</td> 
                                <td style="width:49%"><input type=text ng-model="personal_info_notes">{{myQuestion.notes}} </td>       
                             </tr>                           
                          </tbody>                    
            </table>          
          </div>
           <center><button type=submit id="btn_evaluate">Evaluate Report</button></center>
           <hr>      
          <hr>  
          
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        </center>
      
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src= "scripts/core/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src= "scripts/core/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
      <script src="scripts/controllers/questionnaire.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hey can just fiddle that out?

Comment: New to fiddle. Just trying to check how to put JSON file...

Comment: I tried to replicate in a Plunker your issue but your code is probably incomplete (for example there is no ng-controller directive...). Check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/PNKUkVFpdttVSXV5lVr9?p=preview

Comment: Sorry my bad..! please see the updated and running code over here :           https://plnkr.co/edit/LAcAbRmLKlYLxZnSDP8f?p=preview

Comment: I resolved this problem by adding unique id to the msg div for each question. Please see my updated code with answer here :    https://plnkr.co/edit/J2bNoRUtykL4aE2tfjyb?p=preview

Comment: Thanks folks for your time !!